# Resources$NotFoundException getting a Color - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been programming in `Android + Kotlin` for a long time, and I never had this issue in specific.

I have 2 `colors.xml` files defined, one for Light mode, another for Dark mode:

```
 - res/values/colors.xml
 - res/values-night/colors.xml
```

I have the same `color` identifications on each file, but with different values.

Regardless of which `color` I try to get, using:

```
- ContextCompat.getColor(context, id)
- ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, id, theme)
```

I always get `Resources$NotFoundException`, even though the `color` exists.

If I try to access it using:

```
 resources.getIdentifier("<color_name>", "color", packageName)
```

everything works fine and I get it, but this is not really practical.

res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#fafafa</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor">#c7c7c7</color>
    <color name="secondaryColor">#616161</color>
    <color name="secondaryLightColor">#8e8e8e</color>
    <color name="secondaryDarkColor">#373737</color>
    <color name="primaryTextColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="secondaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="red_light">#cf6679</color>
    <color name="red_dark">#b00020</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_ok_bg">#006400</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_error_bg">#b00020</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_text_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

res/values-night/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#212121</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor">#484848</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="secondaryColor">#757575</color>
    <color name="secondaryLightColor">#a4a4a4</color>
    <color name="secondaryDarkColor">#494949</color>
    <color name="primaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="secondaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="red_light">#cf6679</color>
    <color name="red_dark">#b00020</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_ok_bg">#006400</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_error_bg">#b00020</color>
    <color name="quick_notification_text_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

How I have tried to access it, in an AppCompatActivity and its results:

```
val firstTry = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.quick_notification_text_color)
val secondTry = resources.getColor(R.color.quick_notification_text_color, theme)
val thirdTry = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.quick_notification_text_color, theme)
val getIdentifierTry = resources.getIdentifier("quick_notification_text_color", "color", packageName)

firstTry -> -1
secondTry -> -1
thirdTry -> -1
getIdentifierTry -> 2131034311
```

Does anyone knows what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post  `colors.xml` along with how you are trying to get with `id`

Comment: @rajan.kali Sure, I have edited the post right now.

Comment: Thanks , are your developing mutli module app ? and are you able to navigate to your `color` resource using editor key `cmd + click`?

Comment: No, I'm not developing a multi module app, atleast yet. And yes, I'm able to navigate to the color resource using cmd + click. Everything looks pretty normal and fine, but I simply keep getting ResourceNotFound

Comment: Hmm Strange, did you try cleaning and invalidating the project ? Just in case R file is corrupted or not updated.

Comment: Yes, I did clean the project, Invalidated and Restarted, and it still happens.

Comment: Does `R` import correct and starts with `applicationId` ?

Comment: Yes, already confirmed it too. R is imported correctly according to the application name.

Comment: Thank you for your help rajan and Stanislav.
I added an answer since the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not exactly sure of what I did to fix it, but some steps I took are below:

1. Verified if I was able to navigate to the color using cmd + click
2. Verified if the R class import was correct
3. Cleaned and did Invalidate Cache and Restart
4. Cleared **build** folder inside **app** folder, and **.gradle and .idea** folders inside **project** folder
5. Removed **buildToolsVersion** property from app's gradle file
6. Tried to reduce the **compileSdkVersion** from 30 to 29, it worked, and then I changed back to 30, and it still worked.
7. Added a new color, tested, and it worked. Tried again the first colors, and they started to work too.

So, this is kinda uncertain, but I advise you to try these steps if you have the same problem.